# django large FileField Initialization and Memory

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Another service writes a lot of large Files (around 20 GB) into my Djangos MEDIA directory. Once the Files are complete, a django shell script is executed that attaches the files to a respective filefield of an associated model. Minimal Example:

```
from django.core.files import File

local_file = open("/MEDIA/big_file.dat")
djangofile = File(local_file)
SomeModel.SomeFileField.save('big_file.dat', djangofile)
local_file.close()
```

Can I use an approach like this on a production server, where approx. every minute 2-3 of those 20GB files are created?

My worries are that the python open() or the Django [File()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/core/files/base/#File.open) function (which seems to use open() as well) read the whole file into memory, which would so to speak [overflow my stack](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I don't see a problem with your approach, because `open()` does not actually read the file contents into memory; the reading is done by `.read()` and similar methods, or when iterating over the contents. But have you tried it with a lot of big files in a test environment (or dev server)?

Comment: So far it seems to work on a test environment, but since I have no experience with large Django filefields I wanted to ensure that I don't overlook some obvious issue or best practice approach